# yum plugin to downgrade

Tags: python, linux, redhat, yum

I have written a plugin for yum to remove the specific rpm during downgrade. But I want to remove the rpm before yum will update the other rpms. (want to restrict the order using yum plugins, instead of doing in the spec file)

Can we restrict the order of the update/install/remove/clear/erase during the yum downgrade/upgrade/install procedure in the yum plugins ??

Content of yum plugin:

```
def postresolve_hook(conduit):
        tsInfo = conduit.getTsInfo()
        rpmdb = conduit.getRpmDB()
        oldlen = 0
        while oldlen != len(tsInfo):
                oldlen = len(tsInfo)
                opts , commands = conduit.getCmdLine()
                conduit.info(2, commands[0])
                # If the command line input is 'update'/'upgrade'/'install' and 'sde rpm state is UPDATE' then remove these five rpms. 
                if ( commands[0] == ‘downgrade' ) and ( commands[1] == 'sde' ):
                                for txmbr in tsInfo.getMembersWithState(output_states=[TS_INSTALL]):
                                                if txmbr.name == 'sde' and txmbr.version < '7.30':
                                                                conduit._base.remove(name='tclkit', arch='x86_64')
                                                                conduit._base.downgrade(name='svpermissions', arch='x86_64')  
conduit._base.downgrade(name='svsde', arch='x86_64')
```

Note: I want to restrict the order of the highlighted part. First remove then downgrade other rpms. But yum internally do update/install first as compare to erase/remove.

Comment: What's wrong with yum's existing downgrade functionality?

Comment: Even i have mentioned the remove "tclkit" statement first and then downgrade "svpermissions and svsde", yum will first update the svsde and svpermissions and then it will remove the tclkit. So i want it to restrict the order. "first remove then update"

Comment: If you feel that yum's behavior is buggy then you should report it to the developers.

Comment: I think, after post download of the rpms and just before running the transaction, yum python code has a specific order like 1. Update 2. Install 3. Remove 4. Cleanup for independent rpms and due to this,it is behaving in a particular way, not as I mentioned in plugin.